# Synchronous for loop in Meteorjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I need to call an asynchronous function inside a for loop. The problem is that the order of each function call is important. How can I achieve this with fibers/future/wrapasync within meteor? Thank you!

Edit:
A small clarification of what i want to achieve using typescript:

```
for(let tmp of temps){ 
  insertIntoDB(tmp);
}
```

The problem is that the calls for insertIntoDB should be executed synchronously because it runs some checks where the preciously inputed data is relevant and should be in the database.

Comment: Why not just call the nth+1 function from the return of the nth?

Comment: Please give us more details as to what you want to achieve exactly. It's too vague at the moment...

Comment: I might consider calling the nth+1 function from the previous one, but it doesnt feel too meteoristic and I was expecting a solution which is closer to the way I have seen fibers and wrapAsync used from this community. Nonetheless I'm aware that the proposed solution would work. Also please check the updated question as i tried to make it a bit clearer. Thank you!